# scale, rotate and move with UIGestureRecognizer simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I can't find out why my scale, rotate and move won't work at the same time..

I have looked at a lot of examples and i can't seem to find the problem.
firstly I thought that is was a `gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` problem, but it wasn't please help :)

here is my code:

```
@implementation StoryEditorPageHolderView   
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
- (id)initWithProperty:(Property *)property scale:(CGFloat)scaleFactor pos:(CGPoint)point dustbin:(DustbinView *)dustBin{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    if(self){
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:property.imageName]];


        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height);
        [self addSubview:_imageView];

        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

        UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
        [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfileImageRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [tapProfileImageRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotate {
    if (rotate.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        prevRotation = 0.0;
    }

    float thisRotate = rotate.rotation - prevRotation;
    prevRotation = rotate.rotation;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, thisRotate);
}

- (void)scale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinch {
    if (pinch.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        prevPinchScale = 1.0;

    float thisScale = 1 + (pinch.scale-prevPinchScale);
    prevPinchScale = pinch.scale;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, thisScale, thisScale);
}

-(void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {

    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        prevPanPoint = [pan locationInView:self.superview];
    }

    CGPoint curr = [pan locationInView:self.superview];

    float diffx = curr.x - prevPanPoint.x;
    float diffy = curr.y - prevPanPoint.y;

    CGPoint centre = self.center;
    centre.x += diffx;
    centre.y += diffy;
    self.center = centre;

    prevPanPoint = curr;
}
@end
```

I also have `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` as a `delegate` in the .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@class Property;
@class DustbinView;

@interface StoryEditorPropertyView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfileImageRecognizer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Property *property;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint pointBegin;
@property (nonatomic) bool isRemoveable;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat beginScale;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DustbinView *dustBin;

- (id)initWithProperty:(Property *)property scale:(CGFloat)scaleFactor pos:(CGPoint)point dustbin:(DustbinView *)dustBin;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, what you're doing wrong is not adding an object for the UIGestureRecognizer to adapt to. For example, you have the

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfileImageRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [tapProfileImageRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];
```

This is exactly what you need except this line

```
 [self addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];
```

this is adding the gesture onto the class. you need an OBJECT :)

so just do this

```
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];
```

for all your gestures, and it should work :)
You always have to make sure you're adding onto the object, not the class

Hope this helps!!

EDIT:

Putting UIGestureRecognizers onto UIView is the way that you would do what you are doing. What you need to do now is go under Xcode,

- file -> new file
- make a UIViewController subclass
- make sure that name it...
- under your .xib file, find this:

[image]

Then, if you look at where the UIView is, click that. This will bring up the UIView attributes panel. Travel over to the little button that has the i in the circle. It's the blue one under the Attributes panel. Click that, and you should see this:

[image]

Where you see the box that says 'UIView'

That is where you type your subclass of UIView.

That should help with any of the issues you have been having. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: it tells me that:
Property 'view' not found on object of type 'xxxxxxx'

Comment: what is your class a subclass of?

Comment: are you doing UIViewController, or any other controller? or something like a subclass of UIView?

Comment: Oh! well what you need to do is leave it as self, since you're adding it onto a view already. Now, all you have to do is create a UIViewController class, and inside your .xib file, go to the specs of it's view, and type your UIView subclass, i'll post it in a new answer hang on

Comment: Thanks!! sorry i didn't tell you that in the first place :)

Comment: that's not a problem. Sometimes it doesn't seem like you need that information when really it means the answer to some issues :)

Comment: It's working as i should but just not simultaneously...
why would it work at all if i haven't already done this?

Comment: i'm not fully sure on what you're asking. I thought you were wanting to get the view to do all those? Have you already hooked it up like i showed?

Comment: Right not i can:
Move, scale and rotate the object on the view...
But i cant do these three things simultaneously

Comment: Well, i'm not sure why it won't let you do them all at once. I've been able to do it anytime I have tried. Tell me more about what you're doing with the view

Comment: i'm not sure how to use storyboard/ios 5...im sorry about that

Answer (score -1):

adding gesture code you should put in `viewDidLoad` not in `init` method and add gesture in view(`self.view`) not in object(`self`) itself .
try as follow I made some changes

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

        UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
        [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfileImageRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [tapProfileImageRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: That's true, I didn't see the init method there! haha

Comment: But this is property that will be spawned on user tab after the view is loaded? i cant use the viewDidLoad method then can i?

Comment: They're not using a UIViewController when adding the gestures. It is a  subclass of UIView

Comment: @MadsDonkin see viewDidLoad get called when View component completely loaded and all IB connection done. before viewDidLoad we shouldn't use view & its component. so try once if it doesn't worked for you will see.

Comment: Please tell me more about this class, what it does, is it a controller or view???

Comment: hmm..I think you should add these gestures in to this view at viewDidLoad of the controller where you are creating this view.